# 'Despercudido' con la acepción de 'estar curado de espanto'

Tags: expresiones, palabras-raras, locuciones, significado-en-contexto, modismos

> *Ahora con todo lo que uno ve en internet, cuando me penan o veo un ovni me siento más **despercudido**.*

Penar es el acto de aparición de un fantasma o de una persona que ya falleció a otra.

¿Qué querrá decir con "despercudido"? '*Aliviado*' por lo que sabe o '*preparado/atento*' ante ese tipo de hechos?

*Despabilado*, *despierto* no me calza en este contexto.

> a) Despercudir
> 2. tr. Arg., Chile y Perú. Despabilar, despertar a una persona. U. t. c. prnl.

¿'*Liberado*'? ¿*Open-mind*?

> b) Liberado, da
>
> 1. adj. Dicho de una persona: Libre de convencionalismos morales y sociales. Apl. a pers., u. t. c. s.

O, tal vez, ¿A qué lo digiere, acepta o asimila más rápido?

> c) Despercudido, da
> 2. Chile [persona] Que se muestra rápido en sus razonamientos.

Creo que la opción c) es la más acertada debido a que con esa información ya no se sorprende, no lo toma por sorpresa.

Creo que se asemeja a **estar curado de espanto** (o espantos)
https://www.lexico.com/es/definicion/estar_curado_de_espanto_(o_espantos)

> LOCUCIÓN
>
> 1. Mostrarse impasible ante cierta cosa, que debería impresionar o escandalizar, por estar acostumbrado a ella.

> Estar curado de espanto: Haber tenido la experiencia y por ello no impactarse la segunda vez; ser indiferente a la contrariedad; ser inmune al asombro;

> - Sin embargo, los extraterrestres que aterrizaron aquí en 1989 lo hicieron en una ciudad **curada de espanto** donde había pasado casi de todo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ahora con todo lo que uno ve en internet, cuando me penan o veo un ovni me siento más despercudido*.

---

Desde mi punto de vista, la persona ó autor que ha escrito esta frase no estaba refiriéndose ó al menos, no tenía en mente precisamente, la voz "*despercudido*" que como bien se indica, aparece en el diccionario con las distintas acepciones que se enumeran y que  han sido expuestas.

Más bien parece que el autor ha querido utilizar la palabra "percudido", añadiéndole la partícula ó el prefijo "des", con lo que aparentemente tenemos la misma palabra "despercudido", pero con significados distintos.

La partícula "des", del latín "de" y "dis" (ejem. demitto, dimitto), denotan separación. En Español, indica negación, privación, acción inversa.

Por otro lado, "*Percudir*" se dice del maltrato ó arrugamiento del rostro, penetrar la suciedad, "Penetrar en algo". Por tanto, "des-percudir", significa que no penetra en algo ó penetra menos, es decir, "sin penetración" ó "impenetrable".

A su vez, indagando en el término, "Percudir", procede del latín "Percutio - cussi - cussum 3 (per quatio), Verbo Percutere" con distintos significados, golpear, batir, conmover, abatir, impresionar...

De todo esto se deduce que cuando se relaciona con la expresión "curado de espanto", como acepción, no va mal encaminado. En este sentido "*despercudir*", no tiene el mismo significado que "des-percudir" y a su vez "despercudir", no tiene en cuenta el significado de "percudir" ya que se trata de una palabra totalmente desvinculada, de ahí una posible confusión.

En este sentido, la forma más literal de "des-percudir" indica ó viene a significar con la partícula "des", el aspecto inverso de algo, "menos impresionado", "no penetrado", "sin penetración", "no golpeado" ó "menos golpeado", "menos batido", "menos apedreado", en definitiva más próxima a la expresión "curado de espanto", esto es, acostumbrado a ciertas cosas, ver con impasibilidad, a causa de experiencia o costumbre, desafueros, males o daños.

*Ahora con todo lo que uno ve en internet, cuando me penan o veo un ovni me siento más despercudido*, así se entiende el sentido de **menos impresionado, más curtido, impasible, imperturbable, sin alteración**.

*Sin embargo, los extraterrestres que aterrizaron aquí en 1989 lo hicieron en una ciudad* **impasible, imperturbable, indiferente, menos impresionada,** *donde había pasado casi de todo*.